# Apiary.io, same route different method

Tags: apiblueprint, apiary.io

I'm trying to define a simple CRUD routes in Apiary.io but the interactive editor is complaining because some of my routes are called the same:

```
/questions/{question_id} (GET)
/questions/{question_id} (PUT)
```

*"The resource '/questions/{question_id}' is already defined"*

[image]

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is that I have to not duplicate the resource:

```
## Question [/questions/{question_id}]
```

And just add different actions:

```
### View a Question Detail [GET]
### Update a Question [PUT]
```

More details: http://support.apiary.io/knowledgebase/articles/117119-handling-multiple-actions-on-a-single-resource

Comment: If I am having different value for question_id then how to set it using Parameters help me into this?